# Remove ? and = in a javascript output string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use JS to keep a list of parcels I have sent and to update tracking information on a regular basis. I have a js script that currently is supposed to output a specific URL and to scrape the page to see if there are any keywords contained.

However I am getting the following console output: https://www.royalmail.com/business/track-your-item/?tracking-results=KB654470953GB#/

When the address should be https://www.royalmail.com/business/track-your-item#/tracking-results/KB654470953GB

```
const Item = function(referenceNumber) {

  return {
    referenceNumber: referenceNumber,
    lastStatus: '',
    via: '',
    tracks: [],
    checkedAt: '',
    nextCheck: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), new Date().getHours(), new Date().getMinutes()),
    setNextCheck: function(settings) {

      const baseDate = this.checkedAt || new Date();

      if(settings.checkUnitInterval === 'minute') {

        this.nextCheck.setMinutes(baseDate.getMinutes() + settings.checkInterval);
      }
      else if(settings.checkUnitInterval === 'hour') {

        this.nextCheck.setHours(baseDate.getHours() + settings.checkInterval);
      }
      else if(settings.checkUnitInterval === 'day') {

        this.nextCheck.setDate(baseDate.getDate() + settings.checkInterval);
      }
    }
  }

};

function trackerCallback(response) {

  const html = $.parseHTML(response);
  trackable(html);

}

function trackable(html) {

  const referenceNumber = $(html).find('dl.tnt-block-parcel dd').text();
  const lastStatus = $(html).find("dd.tnt-item-status").text();
  const via = $(html).find('dl.tnt-block-service dd span.description').text('').parent().text().trim();
  const history = $(html).find('table.tnt-tracking-history tbody tr');
  let tracks = [];

  $(history).each( (index, tr) => {

    let track = {

        date: $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
        time: $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
        status: $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
        trackPoint: $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()

    };

    tracks.push(track);

  });

  let item = new Item(referenceNumber);
  item.lastStatus = lastStatus;
  item.checkedAt = new Date();
  item.via = via;
  item.tracks = tracks;

  saveTrackable(item);

  const options = {
    body: `Last status: ${item.lastStatus}\nChecked at: ${formatDate(item.checkedAt)}`,
    icon: '../256x256.png'
   };

   chrome.storage.sync.get('settings', storage => {

    const settings = JSON.parse(storage.settings);

    if (settings.showNotification) {

      new Notification(item.referenceNumber, options);
    }

   });

} 

function tracker(referenceNumber) {

  const url = "https://www.royalmail.com/business/track-your-item/#/";
  const data = {"tracking-results" : referenceNumber};

  $.get(url, data, trackerCallback);

}

function saveTrackable(item) {

  chrome.storage.sync.get(null, (storage) => {

    const settings = JSON.parse(storage.settings);
    let trackItems = [];

    item.setNextCheck(settings);

    if(storage.hasOwnProperty('trackItems')) {

      trackItems = JSON.parse(storage.trackItems);
    }

    const itemExists = trackItems.findIndex(oldItem => oldItem.referenceNumber === item.referenceNumber);

    if(itemExists >= 0) {

      trackItems[itemExists] = item;
    } 
    else {
      trackItems.push(item);
   }

  const save = {'trackItems': JSON.stringify(trackItems)};
  chrome.storage.sync.set(save, () => {

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'loadTrackItems'});
    loadTrackItems();
  });

  });

}

function loadTrackItems() {

  getTrackItems().then( items => {

    const trackItems = document.getElementById('trackItems');

    if (trackItems) {

      trackItems.innerHTML = renderTrackItems(items);
      $('.show-track-history').click( (e) => loadTrackHistory(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.referenceNumber, showTrackHistory));
      $('.remove-trackable').click( (e) => removeTrackable(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.referenceNumber));
      $('.check-now').click( (e) => tracker(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.referenceNumber));
      $('#checkAll').click(checkAll);
    }

    $(trackItems).transition('bounce');

  });

}

function checkAll() {

  getTrackItems().then( items => {

    items.forEach( item => tracker(item.referenceNumber) );
  });


}

function getTrackItems() {

  const promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

    let trackItems = [];

    chrome.storage.sync.get('trackItems', storage => {

      if(storage.hasOwnProperty('trackItems')) {

        trackItems = JSON.parse(storage.trackItems, dateTimeReviver);

      }

      resolve(trackItems);

    });

  });

  return promise;
}
```

Comment: `const url = \`https://www.royalmail.com/business/track-your-item/#/tracking-results/${referenceNumber};\``?

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

You can use the `.replace` method. Check above for documentation.